# ajuda com listview Django

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django

preciso de ajuda para pegar os valores de um objeto em uma list view

```
class Compraslist(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = Solicitacao
template_name = 'compraslist.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Compraslist, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['solicitacoes'] = Solicitacao.objects.all()
    return context
```

essa é minha classe de list, ela lista as solicitações que foram feitas o que preciso é que ela só liste as solicitações que tem o status LiberacaoCompras = 1

```
class Orcamento(models.Model):
anexo_descricao = models.CharField("Descrição do Arquivo" ,max_length=100)
anexo_orcamento = models.FileField("Anexar Arquivo", upload_to='media/uploads/anexos/')
anexo_relacionamento = models.ForeignKey(Solicitacao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ROLE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Sim'),
    (2, 'Não')
)
liberacao_compras = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Aprovar Solicitação?",
    choices=ROLE_CHOICES,
    default = 1,
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.anexo_descricao

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Orcamento'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Orcamentos'
```

tentei pegar pelo `get_context_data` da seguinte forma

```
class Compraslist(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = Solicitacao
template_name = 'compraslist.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Compraslist, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['solicitacoes'] = Solicitacao.objects.all()
    context['anexo'] = Orcamento.objects.filter(anexoRelacionamento=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return context
```

porem foi me retornado um erro

```
   context['anexo'] = Orcamento.objects.filter(anexoRelacionamento=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

KeyError: 'pk'

Comment: O seu filtro deveria ser no model de solicitações. 

Solicitacao.objects.filter(liberacao_compras=1)

O erro do pk é outra coisa. Não está encontrando a chave 'key' nos argumentos vindos do contexto:

tenta:

Orgamento.objects.filter(anexo_relacionamento=kwargs['id'])

os atributos devem ser minúsculos.

Comment: esse `self.kwargs['pk']` se refere ao model `Solicitacao` ou `Orcamento`? qual a url dessa view?

Comment: Esse KeyError pk é porque tu está chamando um parâmetro que não foi passado na sua url.
E da uma lida na documentação do ListView, o correto é você mudar a query no get_queryset e não no get_context_data.

Comment: Os nomes também não estão bons. Você tem uma view chamada ComprasList que usa um model chamado Solicitacao e o parâmetro pk que tu passou chama um model Orcamento. Pense se vale a pena mudar o nome de ComprasList para SolicitacaoDeCompraList ou SolicitacoesList ou algo que prefira. E se você precisa fazer um filtro em Orcamento com o pk, muda o parâmetro da url para orcamento_pk porque normalmente em urls quando usamos 'pk', esse parâmetro é utilizado em algum filtro do modelo principal da view, que no caso é Solicitacao.